# cocos2d-x pthread on android

Tags: android, pthreads, cocos2d-x

I want to load something in background of loading screen(with animations).
I am trying to use pthread, but it is not working on android. On windows no problems with it.

I have thread function like this:

```
static void* ThreadFunction(void *o)
{
    CCMessageBox("ThreadFunction", "MainLayer");
    return NULL;
}
```

And create thread like this:

```
pthread_t thread;
CCMessageBox("pthread_create", "MainLayer");
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, ThreadFunction, 0);
```

On windows all works fine: i see 2 messages. On android i see only first message("pthread_create").

I tryed to create thread in `onEnter`, `onClick`, `constructor` methods of my layer.
I am using cocos2d-x 2.0.4. Can somebody help me?

Comment: CCMessageBox is using the OpenGL context, at least on mobile devices OpenGL functions must be run on the same thread the GL context was created on. This might be different on Windows.

Comment: Ok, i put CCMessageBox just to debug. But without it, i have inside ThreadFunc image download using curl. It is not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `CCHttpClient`.